# Accessing a file share across an ocean (through a VPN)

Tags: windows-server-2008, vpn, network-share

I am in the process of setting up a log shipping scenario with two SQL Servers linked via VPN (Barracuda NG Firewall, for what it's worth). The VPN is using UDP and packet compression, so I don't have the "TCP over TCP" issue. Of course, I need the actual files to get copied across, and I'd like the SQL settings to refer to a drive letter (like L:).

SMB has failed terribly at this, as I expected.

What protocol would do best over a high-latency, high-bandwidth link that would allow me to map the share as a "drive?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll likely need to look into some sort of [WAN optimization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WAN_optimization) appliances and/or software. Riverbed is a big player in this market and they make some very nice gear, but it's not cheap. SMB optimization can make a world of difference in performance over high-latency links, and at a glance, it does look like they support some WAN optimization for SQL traffic as well.

Comment: Log shipping involves moving transaction log backups, which are just plain files. The transport mechanism can be anything. I just need whatever is fastest.

Comment: Well, in that case, any WAN accelerator that supports SMB/CIFS will likely work very well.